# pip-reqs compile only resolves one github zip package from multiple

Tags: python, pip, divio, pip-tools

I have a requirements.in file that only installs one of the packages pointing to github zip URL.

This is how I reproduce the problem. Check out the cases. I always run `pip-reqs compile`.

```
requirements.in:
https://github.com/jrutila/checkout-psp-client/archive/master.zip#egg=checkout-psp-client==0.0.1

results in requirements.txt with:
#
# This file is autogenerated by pip-compile
# To update, run:
#
#    pip-compile --no-index --output-file /workspace/requirements.txt /workspace/requirements.in
#
asgiref==3.3.1            # via django
https://github.com/jrutila/checkout-psp-client/archive/master.zip#egg=checkout-psp-client==0.0.1
django==3.1.7
pytz==2021.1              # via django
sqlparse==0.4.1           # via django
```

Okay, so the `checkout-psp-client` is correctly listed. I run this inside a container and not sure where the django stuff comes from... Let's try adding the next package.

```
requirements.in:
https://github.com/jrutila/checkout-psp-client/archive/master.zip#egg=checkout-psp-client==0.0.1
https://github.com/jrutila/django-slick-reporting/archive/master.zip#egg=django-slick-reporting==0.5.99

results in requirements.txt with:
#
# This file is autogenerated by pip-compile
# To update, run:
#
#    pip-compile --no-index --output-file /workspace/requirements.txt /workspace/requirements.in
#
asgiref==3.3.1            # via django
https://github.com/jrutila/django-slick-reporting/archive/master.zip#egg=django-slick-reporting==0.5.99
django==3.1.7
pytz==2021.1              # via django
sqlparse==0.4.1           # via django
```

No `checkout-psp-client` anymore. Interesting... Let's swap the packages around.

```
requirements.in:
https://github.com/jrutila/django-slick-reporting/archive/master.zip#egg=django-slick-reporting==0.5.99
https://github.com/jrutila/checkout-psp-client/archive/master.zip#egg=checkout-psp-client==0.0.1

results in requirements.txt with:
#
# This file is autogenerated by pip-compile
# To update, run:
#
#    pip-compile --no-index --output-file /workspace/requirements.txt /workspace/requirements.in
#
asgiref==3.3.1            # via django
https://github.com/jrutila/checkout-psp-client/archive/master.zip#egg=checkout-psp-client==0.0.1
django==3.1.7
pytz==2021.1              # via django
sqlparse==0.4.1           # via django
```

Now it is missing the `django-slick-reporting`! Apparently the ordering matters.

What am I missing here? The original file contained many more PyPi packages and one github URL and they were listed correctly. After adding the second github URL it started misbehaving and this is the minimal example I can reproduce this behavior. It seems like I can only include *one* package from external sources. The `pip-reqs compile` does not give any error and there seems to be no verbose option?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get in touch with Divio's support this is a Divio specific tool